# Nokia S60 Java SDK?

Tags: java, java-me, sdk, nokia, s60

I want to develop a Java app for Nokia N70 (S60 platform). Unfortunately, Nokia thinks this phone is way too old and nobody should develop for it. I once used the MIDP SDK 2.1 beta, is there something better?

Comment: Why do you know Nokia is thinking this?

Comment: Because Nokia does not provide links to a useful SDK for this target device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In past I've been done something on S60 platform and SDK 2.1.
Unfortunately I think is the unique...

Moreover symbian will die soon so, make your accounts :)

Answer (score 1):

For older devices, you can use the [oracle javame sdk](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html). The emulator is different. But basic apps will work on the device. Make sure you use midp2.0 and sometimes also cldc 1.0, otherwise app will not start on device.